# Tomcat not recognizing WAR file with specific name

Tags: linux, tomcat7

I have tomcat 7.0.12 installed under `RHEL` 6.3, but it was removed by mistake using remove command form terminal (Tomcat was up and running), after few days I had to deploy another WAR with the same name, what I did is stopped tomcat cleared cache and installed the new WAR, but when Tomcat manager was opened there is no trace to the new WAR (note if I changed the name form MyWAR to myWAR for example I can start it but the name MyWAR is not recognized), please advise.

Comment: Just to check: you're deleting the unpacked WAR when redeploying? Otherwise, you'll keep seeing the old application.

Comment: And delete in the work/Catalina/localhost directory.

Comment: @kaqqao  I deleted the unpacked WAR before redeploying, using rm -Rf MyWAR/

Comment: @mpez0 I removed  work/Catalina directory and tried but the same error ( when tomcat service is down) but still the same issue , then shutdown tomcat again to removed cachedir/packages as well as work/Catalina